# How can i connect Linq with MySql

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to connect my Linq Application with Mysql as DB.  Can i know the best and

possible to ways to connect Linq Application with Mysql and work.

Regards, 
Rajender

Answer (score 0):

Use MySql Connector

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net